# Animating the Removal of a dynamic Angular Component?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

[In this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fadeinout?file=app%2Falert.component.ts) when we click `Create success` the components view display is animated (From opacity 0 to opacity 1 over 5 seconds.).

If we clear the container (`this.container.clear()`) the removal of the element is not animated.  The animations attribute looks like this:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(5000, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(5000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ],
```

How would we enable the triggering of the `leave` animation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your alert.component.ts to this:

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: "alert",
  template: `
     <section [@fadeInOut]>
     <h1 (click)="output.next('output')">Alert {{type}}</h1>
    <section>
  `,
  styles: [`
  :host {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }`],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(5000, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(5000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ],
  host: { '[@fadeInOut]': 'in' }
})
export class AlertComponent {
  @Input() type: string = "success";
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Thanks to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animate-dynamically-created-component?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Awesome!  Any ideas on why that works the way it does?